# Randomize images when refreshing page js html

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a code that should render images randomly using DIV HTML rather than document.write, does anyone have an idea?

```
<script>
var theImages = new Array()

//Random-loading images
theImages[0] = '/img/pirc/hostnger-he.png' // replace with names of images
theImages[1] = '/img/pirc/hostnger-en.png' // replace with names of images


var j = 0
var p = theImages.length;
var preBuffer = new Array()

for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
preBuffer[i] = new Image()
preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
}
var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

function showImage(){
    if(whichImage==0){
    $('.hostnger').html('<a href ="https://www.hostg.xyz/SH1An" target="_blank"><img class="hostnger" src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'"></a>')
    } 

    else if(whichImage==1){
            $('.hostnger').html('<a href ="https://www.hostg.xyz/SH1Ar" target="_blank"><img class="hostnger" src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'"></a>')
    }

}

</script>


<div class="hostnger"></div>
```

Randomize images when refreshing the pageenter code here

Comment: What is the problem. And where is `document.write()`?

Comment: When I put the `document.write () ` it makes me the whole page (every page) for an advertisement and not just a small part that I defined

Answer (score 0):

Where are you actually calling the showImage function?

You should add

```
showImage();
```

somewhere.

Are you including jQuery?

```
$('.hostnger')
```

Is a jQuery call and you are not including jQuery anywhere.